# C++ Builder TtcpClient

Tags: c++, tcp, c++builder, c++builder-xe2

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    int size =  MemoEnter->GetTextLen() + 1;
    wchar_t *szBuff = new wchar_t[size];
    memset(szBuff, 0, sizeof(szBuff));
    MemoEnter->GetTextBuf((wchar_t *)szBuff, size);
    TcpClient->SendBuf(szBuff, sizeof(szBuff));
    LogOut->Lines->Add(szBuff);
    delete []szBuff;
}
```

Why doesn't TcpClient send anything?
Server is ok. connection is ok.
Telnet sends data to the server but this code does not.

Guys! i tried to

```
TcpClient->SendBuf("fsd", 3);
```

and still got nothing

Comment: Did the TcpClient connect OK?  No errors/exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

This may be contributing to the problem:

```
sizeof(szBuff); // Returns the sizeof a wchar_t*,
                // not the number of characters in szBuff
```

Change:

```
memset(szBuff, 0, sizeof(szBuff));
...
TcpClient->SendBuf(szBuff, sizeof(szBuff));
```

To:

```
memset(szBuff, 0, sizeof(wchar_t) * size);
...
TcpClient->SendBuf(szBuff, wcslen(szBuff));
```

If the second argument of `TcpClient->SendBuf()` is the number of bytes, not characters, then change to:

```
TcpClient->SendBuf(szBuff, wcslen(szBuff) * sizeof(wchar_t));
```

Comment: Nope. The problem is in the TcpClient component. memset works fine.

Comment: TcpClient just dont send anything

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `sizeof()` is definately the problem.  You are sending your data specifying the size of the pointer that points at the buffer, not the size of the buffer itself.  The size of a pointer is 4 in 32-bit and 8 in 64-bit.  You need to use the actual buffer size instead of the pointer size.

Rather than using the `new[]` operator, you should use the VCL's `String` class instead, eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{ 
    String s = MemoEnter->Text; 
    TcpClient->SendBuf(s.c_str(), ByteLength(s)); 
    LogOut->Lines->Add(s); 
}
```

Note that `String` is an alias for `UnicodeString`.  If the receiver is not expecting `UTF-16` encoded data, then you need to convert the data to another encoding before you send it, eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{ 
    String s = MemoEnter->Text; 
    UTF8String utf8 = s;
    TcpClient->SendBuf(utf8.c_str(), utf8.Length()); 
    LogOut->Lines->Add(s); 
}
```

Or:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{ 
    String s = MemoEnter->Text; 
    AnsiString ansi = s; // <-- potential data loss for non-ASCII characters!
    TcpClient->SendBuf(ansi.c_str(), ansi.Length()); 
    LogOut->Lines->Add(s); 
}
```

Or:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{ 
    String s = MemoEnter->Text; 
    AnsiStringT<SomeCodePage> ansi = s; // <-- use a suitable codepage to avoid data loss!
    TcpClient->SendBuf(ansi.c_str(), ansi.Length()); 
    LogOut->Lines->Add(s); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for interesting information, but still, it didnt send anything. i mean id doesnt send a bit of a data.just nothing.

Comment: What is the actual return value of `SendBuf()`? It returns the number of bytes accepted into the socket's outbound buffer, or `-1` on error.

Comment: It prints number 22. At http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ScktComp.TCustomWinSocket.SendBuf it says return value is bytes sent

Comment: That documentation is for `TCustomWinSocket`, not `TTcpClient`. But in any case, the return value of `SendBuf()` in either component is the number of bytes that were successfully put into the socket's internal send buffer, not how many bytes were sent over the network. The OS handles the actual transmission in the background. The app has no way of knowing when the actual transmission occurs. If `SendBuf()` returns `22`, then the socket really accepted `22` bytes, and it is out of your hands.  Now you need to double-check that the code on the receiving end is working properly.

Comment: Use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to validate and see when the OS transmits the data over the network, and when it arrives on the other end.

Comment: Sure, i know that real packet size is longer than SendBuf returns. I ment how many bytes sent to internal socket buffer. Ill try the Wireshark

Comment: As I said, `SendBuf()` tells you how many bytes were put in the buffer. That value comes directly from the OS.